# Jest encountered an unexpected token with react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs

So I'm trying to write tests on my React Native app with Jest and TypeScript. While using old babel version everything worked fine, but because of some project problems we had to upgrade babel to 7.0.0. After that I couldn't make it work. Any help is appreciated

**Jest encountered an unexpected token
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".**

/app/node_modules/react-native-calendar-events/index.ios.js:3
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "^1.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^2.3.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.13",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.56.17",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.30",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^4.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.4",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
},


"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button|react-native-calendar-events)/)"
    ]
  }
```

babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": "commonjs"}]],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["react-native", ["@babel/preset-env"]]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the solution. In transform you should use react-native/jest/preprocessor.js instead of babel-jest.

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js" <--- over here
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": []
}
```

Comment: `node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js` doesn't exist for me on RN .70.5, does it need to be installed separately?

Comment: The regex expression `^.+\\.ts?$` will match files ended in `.t`

Answer (score 0):

This is a config that worked for me:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleDirectories: ['./node_modules', 'src'],
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/tests/SvgStub.js'
  },
  setupFiles: ['./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/packages/'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
}
```

babel.config

```
{
   presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
   plugins: [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
   ]
};
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
   
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1",
   
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "@types/pubsub-js": "^1.8.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.40.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.40.1",
    "babel-jest": "29.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "jest-junit": "^14.0.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-mock-imports": "^1.3.8",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
```

Sources: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11591#issuecomment-899508417