# ReferenceError: React is not defined in jest tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have the following line that executes correctly in browser

`eval(Babel.transform(template, { presets: ['react'] }).code);`

but when I run jest tests I am getting `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

What am I missing?

More info:
in the test file I have the following:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
const instance = wrapper.instance();
instance.componentFunction(...)
```

and then the componentFunction has the `eval(Babel.transform(template, { presets: ['react'] }).code);` line where `template` is something it gets from the test file and can be something like `<span>...</span>`

Please let me know if more details are needed

Answer (score 51):

`@babel/preset` already has support for what you need. According to the [react 17 documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) I only had to set the `runtime` to `automatic` in my `babel.config.json`.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-react", {
      "runtime": "automatic"
   }]
  ]
}
```

If you are using [`@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) the config should be

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
      "runtime": "automatic"
    }]
  ]
}
```

The latter is usually not needed since [`@babel/preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) includes `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`.

---

**Why you shouldn't use `import React from 'react';`**

The [documentation states](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html):

- There are some [performance improvements and simplifications](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/createlement-rfc/text/0000-create-element-changes.md#motivation) that `React.createElement` does not allow.

There is also a [technical RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/createlement-rfc/text/0000-create-element-changes.md#detailed-design) that explains how the new transformation works.

If you want to **upgrade**. React also provides an [automated script](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#removing-unused-react-imports) that removes unnecessarry imports from your code.

Comment: For React Native, importing SVG's in test and using TS for tests, the first noted solution worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

Personally I stumbled upon this problem when dealing with Next.js (configured as `jsx: 'preserve'`). If this is a problem with jest working in a Next.js like environment you can configure your babel used by Jest in the same way:

Since next.js already includes the next/babel preset dependency you may as well use and have a setup more consistent with your next.js environment.

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel']
};
```

---

Alternatively, if anyone experienced this bug had the problem wherein `import React from 'react'` is not necessary, because it is already included globally and doesn't need to be included in every file, then this solution may work for you. This may also just be helpful for you if you ever need to import or define global functions for jest.

I simply configured React to be globally defined in jest.

My `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ['./node_modules', 'src'],
  // other important stuff
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/jest-setup.ts']
}
```

My `src/jest-setup.ts` (or make an equivalent `jest-setup.js`):

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';

global.React = React; // this also works for other globally available libraries
```

Now I don't need to worry about each file importing React (even though eslint knows that's unnecessary with Next.js)

Comment: thank you. it was a good workaround in my situation

Answer (score 17):

If you are using JSX in your jest test files, you will need to add the following import line to the top of the file:

```js
import React from 'react';
```

The reason for this is that Babel transforms the JSX syntax into a series of `React.createElement()` calls, and if you fail to import React, those will fail.

Comment: I do have `import React from 'react';` in the `.test` file

Comment: You need also to have it in the _component_ file. E.g., `import React, { Component } from "react";` At least, this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @HawkeyeParker's answer fixed the issue for me - will be including the react import now on any components ( I use next.js so didn't think I had to )

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to import it everywhere if we don't need it? For functional components you don't even use it, the app works fine without importing it, the only problem is jest

Comment: @raquelhortab Depending on your setup you can change your compiler transform configuration. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#how-to-upgrade-to-the-new-jsx-transform for the most common ones. René Link's answer alludes to Babel, which is one of the most common

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after **react-native** and jest and other node_modules related to unit test were upgraded.
Here is my working config:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleDirectories: ['./node_modules', 'src'],
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/tests/SvgStub.js'
  },
  setupFiles: ['./jest-setup.js'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/packages/'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
}
```

For setup file I had to use project specific one `./jest-setup.js` but for a general use `'./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js'` should work too.

babel.config

```
{
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ]
};
```

Sources: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11591#issuecomment-899508417

More info about the dependencies here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74278326/1979861

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing test data in separate test data files that contain JSX, you will also need to import react, as your file contains JSX and so results in a `ReferenceError: React is not defined in jest tests` error.

```
const testData = {
  "userName": "Jane Bloggs",
  "userId": 101,
  "userDetailsLink": <a href="details/101">Jane Bloggs</a>
};
```

importing react, as below, resolves the error.

```
import React from "react";

const testData = {
  "userName": "Jane Bloggs",
  "userId": 101,
  "userDetailsLink": <a href="details/101">Jane Bloggs</a>
};
```

Comment: For me this was not working until I added `import React from 'react';`  and `global.React = React;` to `jest.config.js`